# Make same background color for same items in ListView

Tags: android, listview, background-color

I have a `ListView` and I want to compare my items.
If the item is the same, I want to make the same background color for those items in the `ListView`.
Could you help me please?

Comment: I have a list of people in my listview (name and age). I am comparing the age of these people. If two or more persons have the same age, I want  to put the same color in the listview for those persons.

Comment: AlertDialog alertDialogObject = builder.create();
  ListView listView=alertDialogObject.getListView();  
  listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE)); 
  Producer p1 = null, p2 = null;
  if(p1.getTour().equals(p2.getTour())){
   listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
  }

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an adapter for your list. 
Inside the adapter you can do your stuff like "customize" the layout for the single row

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a custom adapter for the ListView.

In the following adapter (Cursor Adapter for a ListView with an SQL Lite Database query as the source data) the background is set to alternating colors in the **getView** method. The code to detect the same items would likely be more complicated and would depend upon the data.

```
/**
 * Created by Mike092015 on 17/02/2016.
 */
public class Database_Inspector_ProductsDB_Adadpter extends CursorAdapter {
    public Database_Inspector_ProductsDB_Adadpter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertview, parent);
        Context context = view.getContext();
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewroweven));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorlistviewrowodd));
        }
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView textviewproductid = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adipe_productsdb_id);
        TextView textviewproductname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adipe_productsdb_name);
        TextView textviewproductorder = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adipe_productsdb_order);
        TextView textviewproductaisle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adipe_productsdb_aisle);
        TextView textviewproductuses = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adipe_productsdb_uses);
        TextView textviewproductnotes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adipe_productsdb_notes);

        textviewproductid.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_ID_INDEX));
        textviewproductname.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NAME_INDEX));
        textviewproductorder.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_ORDER_INDEX));
        textviewproductaisle.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_AISLE_INDEX));
        textviewproductuses.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_USES_INDEX));
        textviewproductnotes.setText(cursor.getString(ShopperDBHelper.PRODUCTS_COLUMN_NOTES_INDEX));

    };
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_database_inspect_productsdb_entry,parent, false);
    }
}
```